# Button actions and tap gestures are not working on UIView XIB

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, xib

I added custom UIView with XIB. I just tried to perform button actions and tapgestures , nothing is working eventhough user interaction enabled for all elements including ContentView.

Intializing UIView

```
-(void)initializeSubviews {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"DatesView" owner:self options:nil]firstObject];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];

   // self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;

    [self.fromDateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnfromDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.fromDateButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


}
```

Tap gestures

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *fromDateTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnfromDate)];
    [datesView.contentView addGestureRecognizer:fromDateTapRecognizer];
    [datesView.fromMonthYearLabel addGestureRecognizer:fromDateTapRecognizer];
    [datesView.fromDayLabel addGestureRecognizer:fromDateTapRecognizer];
```

Button Action

```
[datesView.fromDateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnfromDate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

UIView interface

[image]

Comment: Can you pass me your xib file so I can try it, Because created by me working fine without any issue. here you can pass mshauket.developer@gmail.com

Comment: datesView is your mainUIView?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things...

1) By commenting out this line in your view subclass:

```
// self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
```

the view ends up with a frame of `0,0`. The button and labels etc are visible because the view defaults to `.clipsToBounds = NO`, but the objects do not receive user interaction.

2) A `UITapGestureRecognizer` is a single instance. If you add it to one view, then try to add it to additional views, it will only exist on the last view to which is was added.

Try it like this (be sure to un-comment the above line):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // do all the loading stuff here...

    // local declaration
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;

    // Optional --- make *sure* user interaction is enabled
    [datesView.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [datesView.fromMonthYearLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [datesView.fromDayLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    // new recognizer
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnfromDate:)];
    // add it to contentView
    [datesView.contentView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    // new recognizer
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnfromDate:)];
    // add it to fromMonthYearLabel
    [datesView.fromMonthYearLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    // new recognizer
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnfromDate:)];
    // add it to fromDayLabel
    [datesView.fromDayLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    // add target action to fromDateButton
    [datesView.fromDateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fromDateButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (void) tapOnfromDate: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Tapped! %@", recognizer.view);
}

- (void) fromDateButtonTapped: (id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button Tapped! %@", sender);
}
```